# What causes this delay in PHP?

Tags: php, irc

I have a question about a PHP script that I wrote to connect to a collect statistics from IRC servers, as a test as I am new to PHP and still learning.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$servers = array(
           "irc.icq.com",
           "irc.quakenet.org"
);

function get_statistics ($server, $port) {
    $nick   = 'IRCDir' . rand(1000, 9999);
    $irc = fsockopen($server, $port);

    fputs($irc,"USER $nick 0 * :$nick\n");
    fputs($irc,"NICK $nick\n");


    while ($data = fgets($irc, 128)) {

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);

        if (isset($ex[0]) && $ex[0] == "PING") {
            fputs($irc, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
        }

        if (count($ex) > 0) {

            if (isset($ex[1]) && $ex[1] == "001") {
                $network = $ex[6];
                echo date('h:i:s') . " network: " . $server;
                echo "\n";
            }

            if (isset($ex[1]) && $ex[1] == "002") {
                $server = str_replace(',', '', $ex[6]);
                echo date('h:i:s') . " server: " . $server;
                echo "\n";
            }

            if (isset($ex[1]) && $ex[1] == "251") {
                $users   = $ex[5] + $ex[8];
                $servers = $ex[11];
                echo date('h:i:s') . " users: " . $users;
                echo "\n";
                echo date('h:i:s') . " servers: " . $servers;
                echo "\n";
            }

            if (isset($ex[1]) && $ex[1] == "252") {
                $ircops = $ex[3];
                echo date('h:i:s') . " ircops: " . $ircops;
                echo "\n";
            }

            if (isset($ex[1]) && $ex[1] == "254") {
                $channels = $ex[3];
                echo date('h:i:s') . " channels: " . $channels;
                echo "\n";
            }

        }

    }
    fclose($irc);
}

foreach ($servers as $server) {
    echo date('h:i:s') . " getting statistics for " . $server;
    echo "\n";
    get_statistics($server, '6667');
}

exit;
?>
```

Here is the output:

```
root@li140-48:~# php bot.php
11:04:23 getting statistics for irc.freenode.net
11:04:24 network: irc.freenode.net
11:04:24 server: sendak.freenode.net
11:04:24 users: 90601
11:04:24 servers: 26
11:04:24 ircops: 22
11:04:24 channels: 50958
11:05:25 getting statistics for irc.icq.com
11:05:26 network: irc.icq.com
11:05:26 server: irc-k01a.orange.icq.com
11:05:26 users: 2671
11:05:26 servers: 3
11:05:26 ircops: 16
11:05:26 channels: 810
11:06:26 getting statistics for irc.quakenet.org
11:06:28 network: irc.quakenet.org
11:06:28 server: blacklotus.ca.us.quakenet.org
11:06:28 users: 37648
11:06:28 servers: 40
11:06:28 ircops: 67
11:06:28 channels: 26711
root@li140-48:~#
```

My question is what causes the delay between the servers being indexed?

At 10.24:19 it has completed the index of `irc.icq.com` so at this point it should disconnect and immediately index the next server in the array, but instead of that it is waiting exactly a minute before doing so, but I have not mentioned a minute in the script?

Hoping some PHP gurus can lend a hand!

Comment: Is it always exactly 60 seconds?

Comment: Considering that it is *exactly* 60 seconds, it looks like PHP is waiting for something, or the IRC server is waiting for something. Either way, something is not letting the connection go, and it has to time out.

Comment: @dwhite.me I am adding more servers to the array and updating the question with more results.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I want the script to close the connection once all of the variables have been collected. I guess I am doing this wrong or have `fclose` in the wrong place ...

Comment: my guess is your pong code is broken and your never making it out of the loop. its always waiting for the server to end the connection.